# magento 2 show attribute value in one block per selected dropdown bundle products

Tags: javascript, php, magento2

We have bundle products with dropdown options. Dropdown options of a bundle product contain the names and SKU number of child product. For example:

[dropdown option of bundle products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Bs3m.png)

What I am trying to achieve: Anytime one item is selected, one block under the selected item show up and show the lead time in this block.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mg1eK.jpg)

Could anybody give me a hint how to solve this task?

Thanks a lot for your help!